# Combination of elements in a list with constraints

Tags: python, list, combinations

I am writing a python code and I need help with a task. I have a list of 8 elements

```
[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H]
```

and I need to find all the combinations of shorter lists (4 elements) in lexicographic order such that two elements are taken from the subset `A,C,E,G` and the other two from `B,D,F,H`. I know that there is the library `itertools`, but I don't know how to combine its functions properly to perform this task

Comment: A = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H] then B = [A[2*k] for k in range(4)] and C =  [A[2*k+1] for k in range(4)] works if your list are always of length 8.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not what I've asked. I need the set of all the new lists with length 4 such that the first two elements are taken from A,C,E,G and the other two are from B,D,F,H and I need them to be in lexicographic order. It is a combinatory task

Comment: Can you provide an example array so we know what the input looks like? Are we dealing with strings or numbers? Is it it the input or the output that has to be lexicographically sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

> I need the set of all the new lists with length 4 such that the first two elements are taken from A,C,E,G and the other two are from B,D,F,H and I need them to be in lexicographic order.

We get the possible starting letters and ending letters then combine all possible pairs of each of them into `all_lists`:

```py
from itertools import combinations

lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']

starters = lst[::2] # ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G']
enders = lst[1::2] # ['B', 'D', 'F', 'H']

all_lists = []

for a in combinations(starters, 2):
    for b in combinations(enders, 2):
        all_lists.append(sorted(a + b)) 

print(all_lists) # Gives [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'H'], ['A', 'C', 'D', 'F'], ['A', 'C', 'D', 'H'], ['A', 'C', 'F', 'H'], ...
print(all_lists == sorted(all_lists)) # False now
```

(Updated to sort each mini-list.)

Come to think of it you could maybe do the second part with `itertools.product`.

Comment: Not bad, but the output I would like to get is like [A, B, C, D], [A, B, C, F], ... I mean, the order must be the same of the original list, I don't know if I explained this point well

Comment: @Ehub Ah, then you could `sorted(a + b)` instead of `list(a + b)` if I understand rightly. See edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The wording of the question is unclear, but I think this is what you want:

```py
array = ['f','g','d','e','c','b','h','a']
first = sorted(array[::2]) # ['c', 'd', 'f', 'h']
second = sorted(array[1::2]) # ['a', 'b', 'e', 'g']
```

Comment: I edited the question in order to be more clear. This is not what I have asked, sorry if I haven't been clear enough